# Get neo4j uptime using cypher

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I need to make a query to get the uptime of a neo4j database that I connect to remotely.
I have been looking at the documentation, especially the cypher console as it is the one I use to connect to neo4j but I can't find anything about the uptime.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there is an option to get the uptime with the following Cypher statement:

```
call dbms.queryJmx("java.lang:type=Runtime") 
yield attributes 
return attributes.Uptime
```